# Pause opening div onmouseover

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how to open a hidden div with javascript but after a user has hovered over a link for one second rather than immediately.  I want to do this, as right now you sweep the mouse across the page and these divs open even though I haven't purposely hovered over them. I **dont** want to use jQuery

This is the code I have in place:

```
function ShowMemberCats()
{
     // TURN OFF OTHER FRAMES //
     document.getElementById('BlogCats').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('VideoCats').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('AudioCats').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('ImageCats').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('CouponCats').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('AdsCats').style.display = 'none';
     // OPEN VIDEO FRAME //
     document.getElementById('MemberCats').style.display = '';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Many thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

When the cursor is over a link (`onmouseover`), start a timer (`setTimeout`).
If this timer reaches 1 second, display your div.
If the cursor leaves the link (`onmouseout`), cancel your timer (`clearTimeout`).

Answer (score 1):

This concept is shown quite nicely [here](http://www.astral-consultancy.co.uk/cgi-bin/hunbug/doco.cgi?11570). It is not exactly the same, nor that elegant, but it shows the principle of what you are wanting to achieve.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var ie = document.all;
  var timeoutId;
  var timeoutObj;

  document.onmouseover = function(e) {
    var obj = ie ? event.srcElement : e.target;
    if (obj.className=='testblock') {
      timeoutObj = obj;
      timeoutId = setTimeout("delay()", 2000);
    }
  }

  document.onmouseout = function(e) {
    var obj = ie ? event.srcElement : e.target;
    if ((obj.className=='testblock') && timeoutId )
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }

  function delay() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = timeoutObj.style.backgroundColor;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: I use global event handlers a bit like your example most of the time, they a very powerful and flexible.